# How can I refresh a fragment after coming back from an activity?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have a menu button that starts a new activity and when it's done the user presses a button and it writes data to an SQLite DB and finishes the activity. But the Fragment that it comes back to shows that information and it's not refreshing when the activity is finished. How can I make sure that the data is refreshed when I come back to the fragment?

I'm using startActivityForResult() and catching the result with the code below but I still do not get a refresh of the fragment

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if ((requestCode == MainActivity.MYACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) && (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK))
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this is to use [startActivityForResult(intent, MyStatusCode)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) and then capture the return by using something like:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
  if (requestCode == MyStatusCode) {
     //Refresh the fragment here
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it just starts the activity again. I'll update my question with the code I currently have.

Comment: Should the onActivityResult() go in the fragment or my main activity?

Comment: What would I use to refresh the fragment? It's a ListFragment and I've tried calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` but that still doesn't refresh the list.

Comment: I made a static method in my fragment and called it from the main activity's `onActivityResult()` and it's working. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

you can use 
`onStart()`
this method called when the fragment gets visible or focus.

Answer (score 1):

The another way to solve this

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_message, container, false);}
```

just inflate views  and adapter or something dont  do anything
and

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    logiMessages.clear();//clear array
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // notify adapter 
    getData(mParam1, mParam2); // getdatas from service 
}
```